# Como criar dois menus diferentes e ativar responsivo com medidas diferentes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Criei dois menus em bootstrap e queria que um a baixo dos 1200px se torna-se com i con toggle e o segundo a baixo de 768px, só ai fica-se responsivo, no entanto nos dois ficam com o icon aos 1200px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar as classes css ".hidden-xs", ".hidden-sm", ".hidden-md".

Segue o link na documentação: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities